# Enum typed properties in Entity Framework entities?

Tags: entity-framework, enums

Is there a way I can map generated entities to enum?

And what I mean is simple:

```
class Person
{
    RelationshipStaus RelationshipStatus { get; set; }
}

enum RelationshipStatus : byte
{
    Single,
    Married,
    Divorced
}
```

The property RelationshipStatus in the DB is a simple byte, I want that in my project it should be an enum.

Comment: EF6 now supports enum mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are supported on EF ≥ 5.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't, at least not directly. For convenience, you can create an accessor that converts the value to and from the enum type:

```
public int RelationshipStatusInt { get; set; }

public RelationshipStatus RelationshipStatus
{
    get { return (RelationshipStatus)RelationshipStatusInt; }
    set { RelationshipStatusInt = (int)value; }
}
```

However you won't be able to use that properties in Linq to EF queries, because it won't be mapped to a DB column (but you can use it in Linq to Objects queries).

Another solution is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4), but it feels a bit awkward...

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas said, there is no solution.

I would just recommend users who encountered the desire to use enums in EF, and vote for this connection: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015335-support-for-enums

Comment: I would love to, but the link you posted isn't working for me.